# No module named 'scrapy.conf'

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to execute Twitter scraper code from: https://github.com/jonbakerfish/TweetScraper

When I run the command `scrapy list` in the command prompt to ensure the scraper is properly set up, I get the following error:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.conf'".
```

I have tried to reinstall scrapy and many other ways, but it seems in vain. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

As Augusto Men has mentioned above, `scrapy.conf` was deprecated. To access the project settings with Scrapy >= v1.7 you use:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()
# Use the settings
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the place to ask this would be Stack Overflow, but to answer your question, the module `scrapy.conf` was deprecated and removed in Scrapy 1.7 (http://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#deprecation-removals).